# Can we access functions outside of stateless component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, static, stateless

Trying to invoke modal function from outside, but not possible. Achieved with class component using static method and properties, but `this` will not work there. Observers are giving some issues, finally landing to stateless component. How best way we can make this work?

```
//Inside
import Modal from './modal';
   // Not working
   <Button onClick={Modal.showModal}
<Modal />


//Outside

export const Modal = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const showModal = () => {
     setVisible(true);
  }
  return(
     <Dialog visible={visible}>Hello Test</h1>
  )
}
```

Comment: That's why there is state management like solution . In your case you can simply use [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

Comment: How to use here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent please look at this link.

Comment: [This](https://daveceddia.com/usecontext-hook/) can help if stuck I will add the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can declare setVisible in parent component:

```
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);
```

Then pass the set function to Modal:

```
 <Modal visible={visible} setVisible={setVisible} />
```

Set visible from outside:

```
  <button onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>Click</button>
```

Sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-bassi-x3dqd?file=/src/App.js:267-325

Comment: Thanks for your response, but is there a better solution than this rather than props? Because the component is mounted already and the state should be changed invoking a function inside

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ["lift the state up"](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a component that will pass the state and the state handlers to his children, or use some global state with [**`redux`**](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) or [**`context`**](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

## Example:

### **`<App>`**:

```
import Modal from "./modal";
import { useState } from "react";

const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

const showModal = () => {
  setVisible(true);
};

return (
  <> 
    <Button onClick={showModal}> Hide Modal </Button>
    <Modal visible={visible} />
  </>
);
```

### **`<Modal>`**:

```
export default const Modal = ({ visible }) => {
  return (
    <Dialog visible={visible}>
      <h1>Hello Test</h1>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

Also, by only using the `export` keyword, you can import only single export from a module, therefore you can't use the **default import** syntax `import Modal from "..."`
and you will be required to import as such - `import { Modal } from '...'`

Comment: there are lot more state setting, so i should invoke a function so that internal function should update the local state without redux

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve usingEffect here, but not sure if this is perfect for my implementation. I am trying to update the state for already mounted component.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.visible) {
      showModal();
    }
  }, [props.visible]);
```

And handled resetState with a callback prop